# After successfull wordpress login, redirected to profile, but session value not setting

Tags: wordpress, session

I am using wordpress website, and it was working fine . Now without any change, when i login, its showing successful and redirected to profile, but session value not set and because of that login option again showing in menu instead of user avatar image. Please help me. Wordpress version 5.3.2. Elementor popup login form i am using. Buddypress and ultimate member plugin is using.

Comment: Have you changed some source-code, then please provide a [example]. Additionally screenshots may help to understand the page flow. Did you do research on the sister-site: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: The version upgraded to new version  Version 5.3.2. When i write a hook to execute after login of user, its execution, then again showing login option in website. I checked with ultimate member login also. Now elementor login popup form is in my website. In both case same issue happening.